# Converting HTML to PDF from https requiring authentication

Tags: authentication, ssl, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I've been trying to convert html to pdf from my company's https secured authentication required web.

I tried directly converting it with pdfkit first.

```
    pdfkit.from_url("https://companywebsite.com", 'output.pdf')
```

However I'm receiving these errors

```
Error: Authentication Required                                    
Error: Failed to load https://companywebsite.com, 
with network status code 204 and http status code 401 - Host requires authentication
```

So I added options to argument

```
pdfkit.from_url("https://companywebsite.com", 'output.pdf', options=options)
options = {'username': username,
           'password': password}
```

It's loading forever without any output

My second method was to try creating session with requests

```
def download(session,username,password):
session.get('https://companywebsite.com', auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username,password),verify=False)

ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
session.headers = {'User-Agent': ua}
payload = {'UserName':username,
    'Password':password,
    'AuthMethod':'FormsAuthentication'}

session.post('https://companywebsite.com', data = payload, headers = session.headers)
my_html = session.get('https://companywebsite.com/thepageiwant')
my_pdf = open('myfile.html','wb+')
my_pdf.write(my_html.content)
my_pdf.close()

path_wkthmltopdf = 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=bytes(path_wkthmltopdf, 'utf8'))


pdfkit.from_file('myfile.html', 'out.pdf')

download(session,username,password)
```

Could someone help me, I am getting 200 from  session.get so its definitely getting the session

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using selenium to access to that site and snap the screenshot